# apache cassandra - Inconsistency between number of records returned and count(*) result

Tags: import, cassandra

I am importing some data into a table in Apache Cassandra using COPY command.  I have 7 rows in my csv files. But after importing I just have 1 row instead of 7 rows. What would make this inconsistency?
[attached is the image of my cqlsh screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ku6B.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible issue:

- same clustering key for the rows.

Solution

- try adding another column as clustering key (domain specific) that gives the rows uniqueness.